# Select min value from multiple column

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, derby

I have a following SCORE table in database :

```
        id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
        1     40    100    80      90
        2     90     70    90      45
        3     50     60    100     30
        4     20     30    30      40
```

I want to select the minimum value from column val1,val2 and val3 and store it in a variable using this code :

```
int maxVal = 0;
Statement s2 = conn.createStatement();
s2.execute("SELECT min(val1,val2,val3) FROM SCORE");    
ResultSet rs1 = s2.getResultSet(); // 
while ( rs1.next() ){
        maxVal = rs1.getDouble(1);
}
```

and got an error. Is there an easy way to get a min value from more than 1 column in a table?

Comment: SELECT min(val1), min(val2), min(val3) FROM SCORE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can get the min from Java code like this :

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT min(val1), min(val2), min(val3) FROM SCORE");

if (rs.next()) {
    minValue = DoubleStream.of(
            rs.getDouble(1), rs.getDouble(2), rs.getDouble(3)
    ).min().getAsDouble();
}
```

---

If you are using less than Java 8 you can use :

```
if (rs.next()) {
    minValue = Math.min(Math.min(rs.getDouble(1), rs.getDouble(2)), rs.getDouble(3));
}
```

Comment: Still showing the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column 25.

Comment: @DonQuixote I think this was not possible in SQL, I changed the solution completely check my edit

Comment: Nope. cannot find the symbol DoubleStream

Comment: @DonQuixote `DoubleStream` exist in java 8 you can check my second solution which use `Math.min`

Answer (score 2):

I came up with

```
SELECT MIN(val)
FROM (SELECT MIN(val1) AS val FROM SCORE
      UNION SELECT MIN(val2) FROM SCORE
      UNION SELECT MIN(val3) FROM SCORE)
```

Comment: I THINK this is closer to what the question is actually looking for, though it's not entirely clear the way it's worded if they're looking for one value or 3.